# Nginx ingress controller redirects the url to /login

Tags: nginx, ingress, azure-kubernetes-service

I am trying to access a url example.com/service/test1 but it redircts me to example.com/login.

Below is my YAMl file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ing
  namespace: test
  annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
     nginx-ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true

spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: svc-test
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /service/test
  tls:
  - secretName: tls-secret
```

Answer (score 3):

## It just works

Your configuration is correct.

Provided `YAML` file generates `nginx` config like this:

```
...
server {
 listen       80;
 server_name  example.com;
 ...
 location ~* "^/service/test" {
   root    /var/www/example.com/htdocs;
 }
}
```

Testing this config via [this cool tester](https://nginx.viraptor.info/) shows that location filter works:

- `http://example.com/service/test1` -> `Location: ^/service/test`
- `http://example.com/service/test` -> `Location: ^/service/test`
- `http://example.com/login` -> `Errors: No locations matched`

For more details, see [this explanation of Ingress Path Matching](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/5f2f0e5db3c3defd34da943002fd6c96835efcbc/docs/user-guide/ingress-path-matching.md) and examples from [NGINX Docs](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/configuration-examples/):

> - [*Examples*](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.6.3/examples) show how to use advanced NGINX features in Ingress resources with annotations.
> - [*Examples of Custom Resources*](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/v1.6.3/examples-of-custom-resources) show how to use VirtualServer and VirtualServerResources for a few use cases.

## Check your app

Check your app, maybe it forward non-authorized requests to `/login` url.
You may use `curl -v` or `wget`, e.g:

```
curl -v -L http://example.com/service/test1 | egrep "^> (Host:|GET)"
```

```
wget  http://example.com/service/test1 2>&1 | grep Location
```

## Howto debug `nginx ingress`

There is an [`Nginx` debug mode](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html) for debugging `nginx` `locations` and redirects.
To enable it, use `--v=5` in `kubectl edit deploy`.

See: [k8s debug logging](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/#debug-logging):

> Using the flag `--v=XX` it is possible to increase the level of logging. This is performed by editing the deployment.
>
> ```
> $ kubectl get deploy -n <namespace-of-ingress-controller>
> NAME                       DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
> default-http-backend       1         1         1            1           35m
> nginx-ingress-controller   1         1         1            1           35m
>
> $ kubectl edit deploy -n <namespace-of-ingress-controller> nginx-ingress-controller
> # Add --v=X to "- args", where X is an integer
> ```
>
> > - `--v=2` shows details using `diff` about the changes in the configuration in nginx
> > - `--v=3` shows details about the service, Ingress rule, endpoint changes and it dumps the nginx configuration in JSON format
> > - `--v=5` configures NGINX in [debug mode](http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html)

Comment: The /login page was coming from the container, it was not the nginx redirects. Thanks, debug mode helped in unfold the ingress

Comment: Hi @pradeep-upadhyay. Glad that my answer helped you. Correct, `nginx` redirects work as I described. And redirects to `/login` was due to application. As I wrote: 'Your configuration is correct.'